# Tricky ArrayList conversion in Java

Tags: java, list, loops

I have this list of *strings* `[20, 3, 11, 15, 27, 5, 6, 29, 7, 30, 15, 9]`
and I want to convert it to this list of *integers* `[33, 75, 42, 135]` each element represents the smallest product of 2 numbers in every 3-number sequence.
For example, 20 * 3=60, 20 * 11=220, 11 * 3= 33 : we'll take 33 in this case, we move on and apply it now the second sequence of 3 which [15,27,5] we get 15 * 5=75 and so on..

I'm struggling with what to do with the index after making 3 iterations over the first sequence, because when I do `index<3` (3 iteration are 0,1,2) when it reaches 3 it goes out, and I don't want that because I want this same loop to do my second sequence.

I might be missing something obvious, but any help is appreciated!

````java
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
       
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("file-name.txt"));

        List<String> listFromFile = new ArrayList<>();
        while (scanner.hasNext()){
            listFromFile.add(scanner.next());
        }
        scanner.close();

        ArrayList<String> purgedList = new ArrayList<>(listFromFile.size()*3);
        for (String s : listFromFile) {
            purgedList.addAll(Arrays.asList(s.split("x")));
        }

        for (String st : purgedList) {
     /* I need to add code that does that here, ofc using parseInt 
      because my elements are strings, and I need to have them as 
      integers to make the multiplication happen then call a min 
    function that takes these 3 products, I guess I'll be using 
    Collections.min for that, the problem idk what logic to follow 
    (how should I create my loops)...ofc suggest other stuff if you
    think making one list is not enough or anything :)*/

        }
    ```
````

Comment: You need to share your code so we can see what's wrong with your code.

Comment: do we need to consider negative numbers?

Comment: The problem I'm working on is big, I can't share it altogether. But this is the part I'm struggling with, so I gave a small example of what it looks like. I don't *know* how to do it, it's not like my code doesn't work or something. @DonBranson

Comment: I don't think I've written down any negatives there. I confirm, no negatives! @LoveshDongre

Comment: @serving__ Please extract the code you have so far for the solution of this problem and ask a more specific question.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that the length of input array is divisible by 3?

Comment: @LoveshDongre not necessarily, I just gave an example.

Comment: @Turing85 I did

Comment: You won't get far with a `foreach`-loop. Think about it this way: each sequence of three consecutive numbers has a start-index. Iterate over all possible start indices for those sequences, read the three values, then do the necessary calculation and determine the result.

Comment: iterate over all possible start indices? does that mean I go i +=3 everytime?
read the three values? how with a nested loop, this part I don't understand much.

Comment: Try [Tricky ArrayList conversion in Java(Java) | Online editor and compiler](https://paiza.io/projects/bMtrRM-aBr-ef3peZt_psQ?locale=en-us)

Comment: Thanks, man! @saka1029 I really like your touch!